# enable a dropdown,textbox from cs file c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

How to enable a disabled dropdown,textbox from cs file C#

```
 public void fill_name_selectedindexchanged(object sender, EventArgs ex)
{
    //txt_name.Enabled = true;
    ddl_title.Attributes.Add("enabled", "enabled");
    txt_full_name.Attributes.Add("enabled", "enabled");
    txt_login_name.Attributes.Add("enabled", "enabled");
    txt_email.Attributes.Add("enabled", "enabled");
    txtDefaultCompany.Attributes.Add("enabled", "enabled");

    //txt_name.Text = "";
    ddl_title.Items.Clear();
    txt_full_name.Text = "";
    txt_login_name.Text = "";
    txt_password.Text = "";
    txt_email.Text = "";
    AutoCompleteExtender1.ContextKey = ddl_user_type.SelectedValue.Trim();
    string val = ddl_user_type.SelectedValue;
    if (val.Trim() == "N")
    {
        ddl_title.Attributes.Add("enabled", "enabled");
        txt_full_name.Attributes.Add("enabled", "enabled");
        txt_login_name.Attributes.Add("enabled", "enabled");
        txt_email.Attributes.Add("enabled", "enabled");
        txtDefaultCompany.Attributes.Add("enabled", "enabled");
        txt_full_name.Text = "";
        txt_login_name.Text = "";
        txt_email.Text = "";
        mm.getlookup(ddl_title, "title", "u");
    }
}
```

The dropdown and the textbox remains disabled,it doesn't change to enable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in addition to the ans given by Rody.
i wanna add that u can put an attribute `disabled` and its value to `disabled` to disable but 
there is no attribute `enabled`. to enable an html input control you will have to remove the `disabled` attribute and not add an `enabled` attribute

Answer (score 3):

`Enabled` is used like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Enabled="False"> 
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

And you can do this server-side as well:

```
DropDownList1.Enabled = false;
```

To set the `disabled` attribute on a server-control, you would have to use:

```
DropDownList1.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
```

Or to enable it:

```
 DropDownList1.Attributes.Remove("disabled");
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm presuming you are using server controls like ASP `TextBox`? Then you can just use:

```
txt_full_name.Enabled = true;
```